# Confusion regarding the constructor property of the string

Tags: javascript

I have been following javascript tutorial from www.w3school.com and while reading one of the examples i have got one question in my mind, the code is as follows:

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

 var txt =new String ("Hello World!");
 document.write(txt.constructor);

 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, iam getting in response of this code is :

```
function String() { [native code] }
```

However, according to me the constructor must have a parameter in it somewhat like this:

```
function string(value){}
```

Can anybody please tell me why it is returning the constructor with no parameter.

Comment: In js arguments are implicit https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even no parameter defined in a JavaScript function, we still can get the parameters with `arguments`:

```
function test() {
  console.log(arguments);
}

test(1,3,6); // Output "[1,3,6]" in console.
```

Answer (score 0):

The other comments are true, but they don't address your question. The reason you're not seeing any parameters, and why it's saying "[native code]" instead of the actual content of the function, is that window.String is a native function - it is not a reference to a javascript function, but instead a symbol that instructs the browser what to do when it's running your javascript. Think of it as more analogous to a plus sign than a function.